# AstroJS can't import * from React Icons due to outside of module error

Tags: reactjs, astrojs, react-icons

I want to dynamically import icons from React-Icons. So, I begin by importing all icons from the sets I intend to use via:

```
import * as FontAwesome from 'react-icons/fa';
```

However, this results in this error:

```
C:\...\astro-portfolio-blog\node_modules\.pnpm\react-icons@4.12.0_react@17.0.2\node_modules\react-icons\io\index.esm.js:2
import { GenIcon } from '../lib';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I removed the import statement, and it resulted in the same error but for the following icon set import, e.g.

```
import * as IonIcons from 'react-icons/io';
```

How can I dynamically import and use react-icons with Astro?

Comment: It’s a CJS mixed with ESM related problem: https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/issues/717